# Changing the shape of a new assigned variable in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

if you change a tf.Variable using [tf.assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) with `validate_shape=False` [the shape is not updated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10091).

But if I use [set_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#set_shape) to set the new (correct) shape I get a ValueError.

Here a quick example:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

a = tf.Variable([3,3,3])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # [3 3 3]
    print(sess.run(a))

    sess.run(tf.assign(a, [4,4,4,4], validate_shape=False))
    # [4 4 4 4]
    print(sess.run(a))

# (3,)
print(a.get_shape())

# ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 4. Shapes are [3] and [4].
a.set_shape([4])
```

How do I change the shape of the Variable?

Note: I am aware that the code works if I use `a = tf.Variable([3,3,3], validate_shape=False)` but in my context I will not be able to initialize the variable myself.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the static part of the graph that the shape is unknown from the start as well.

```
a = tf.Variable([3,3,3], validate_shape=False)
```

Now, to get the shape, you cannot know statically, so you have to ask the session, which makes perfect sense:

```
print(sess.run(tf.shape(a)))
```